# How to get search result when typing without hiting enter button or submit button?

Tags: javascript, json, rest

My code is working fine, but the problem is I am unable to find solution how to show search result without hitting enter button or submit button. I mean I want to show my search result from JSON file when user start typing in search input field. Anybody can help? I'll appreciate it.Thanks

The code that I have tried.

```js
const result = document.getElementById('result');

const userAction = async(event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(todos => {
      todos.forEach((todo) => {
        result.innerHTML = `${todo.userId} ${todo.id} ${todo.title} ${todo.completed}`;
      });
    })
}
```

```html
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="searchName" class="form-control" placeholder="Lorem name">
  <button onclick="searchAction(event)" class="search-icon"><img src="images/search-icon.svg" alt="submit"></button>
</form>
<div class="dropbox">
  <p id="list"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: One thing I'd recommend is to store the results of the fetch on page load, that way you're not making an http request every. single. time. the user types/backspaces in the form :)

Comment: This code doesn't appear to do any actual searching of the data. As far as I can see it will just display the same results every time.

Answer (score 1):

By using the [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event), you can run your code every time a key is pressed (or some other change occurs) in the input field.

Example code from the link above:

```
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const log = document.getElementById('values');

input.addEventListener('input', updateValue);

function updateValue(e) {
  log.textContent = e.target.value;
}
```

Note that by using this, you'll be making one AJAX call per keypress. Since this may spam the server with too many useless requests, you may want to build in some caching or rate-limiting functionality (such as only fetching data if no key has been pressed for a second).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please show me in code snippet because I am bit confused here how to add your code into my code.Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it won't be the only change you'll have to do, but start removing `onclick` event from button. Instead, add `onkeyup` event on the text input. [Here on MDN you can find all events exposed by default.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)